# XML to SQL Table - Getting Blanks

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xml-parsing

**The problem**

I need to take data from XML files provided by another application. These XMLs contain data that is required to be inserted into tables for a database for a different application.

The problem is this, I can't get the values out of the XML file. I keep getting blank/null values instead.

I am using SQL Server 2014 Management Studio.

**What I've tried**

I've looked into how to read an XML and have that placed into a table. I've gone as far as looking at tutorials that work. But, whenever I try to apply the same process to my tables and using my XML data I keep getting blank values.

Some help would be appreciated as I have been looking into this for a day and researching how to approach this using MS SQL. And I cannot for the life of me understand why I keep getting nulls.

**The XML**

```
<DistributionOrder xmlns="a-url">
    <Date>2019-03-07T14:38:00</Date>
    <Order_Number>ACME01</Order_Number>
    <Comment/>
    <Status>Active</Status>
    <Lines>
        <Line>
            <Order_Line_Number>1</Order_Line_Number>
            <Product>22</Product>
            <Status_Line>Active</Status_Line>
            <Comment_Line/>
            <Location>ENT_78</Location>
        </Line>
    </Lines>
</DistributionOrder>
```

**The query**

```
DECLARE @xmlData XML;

INSERT INTO dbo.XMLwithOpenXML(XML_data)
    SELECT * 
    FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\test_file.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS ImportSource;

SELECT * FROM XMLwithOpenXML;

SELECT
    element.value('(Order_Line_Number/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(80)') AS Order_Line_Number,
    element.value('(Product/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(80)') AS Product
FROM
    XMLwithOpenXML 
CROSS APPLY
    XML_data.nodes('DistributionOrder/Lines/Line') AS DO(element)
GO
```

**What I expect**

```
Order_Line_Number | Product
------------------+----------
        1         |   22
```

**What I Get**

```
Order_Line_Number | Product
------------------+----------
                  |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out that the,

```
<DistributionOrder xmlns="a-url">
</DistributionOrder>
```

was the problem. I deleted the xmlns="a-url" from the xml and found that my code is working.

Discovered that you can use

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'a-url')
```

To take the namespace into account.